# AzureStorageQueue ReceiveMessageAsync Concurrent Performance

Tags: azure, queue, azure-storage

We are trying to use AzureStorageQueue for a FIFO mechanism to 'pop' one of the top of the queue.

However, it seems to be performing rather poorly. We are just running the following code below:

```
using (var rootOperation = _telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("PerfTest-ReceiveMessagesAsync"))
                {
                    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                    sw.Start();
                    retrievedMessage = await theQueue.ReceiveMessagesAsync(1);
                    sw.Stop();
                    theMessage = retrievedMessage[0].Body.ToString();
                    _telemetryClient.TrackTrace("SW: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + ", " + theMessage);
                }
```

But if we make 400 requests, the response time is around 4.9 seconds for each.

The ReceiveMessagesAsync seem to be the slow part, and the bottleneck.

But based on Microsoft Documentation, AzureStorage Queue should be able to handle 2000 concurrent requests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/scalability-targets

theQueue is Singleton. We are using Standard Pricing Tier of Azure Storage.

Comment: Can you share the complete code? 4.9 seconds for a single request is definitely not normal.

Comment: Actually, it is already all the code :( We just initialize the queue normal way : _queue = new QueueClient(connstring, queuename).

Queue is a singleton

Comment: A bit late, but I found that the overhead was happening at it's worst when the queue was empty.  We sorted this by doing a PeekMessageAsync before ReceiveMessagesAsync and not attempting it if the queue was empty